# Is there a way to multiply a specific value in a dictionary by n integer?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a dictionary and multiplies a specific value by 2.

**EDIT:** The below appears to be a simple error. Instead of `return getdoubleage(profile["age"])`, it would be `return profile["age"]`.

***Caleb Goodman and S Vengat answered the issue below, if anyone is running into the same issues.***

```
def getdoubleage(profile):

    return getdoubleage(profile["age"]) * 2


print(getdoubleage({"name": "Bob", "age": 10}))     # => 20
print(getdoubleage({"name": "Steve", "age": 20}))   # => 40
```

I'm expecting [below] for my outputs.

> 20
>
> 40

This is the TypeError I'm receiving.

```
  File "/Users/peteryoon/PycharmProjects/Test3/Test3.py", line 3, in getdoubleage
    return getdoubleage(profile["age"]) * 2
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Change the return type to this ````return profile["age"] * 2````

Comment: `getdoubleage()` calls itself recursively, forever.

Comment: Read your code carefully and explain, in your own words, *every part of* the line where the error occurs, and its intended purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
def getdoubleage(person):
    person["age"] *= 2
    return person
```

Think this works.

Edit: To explain the error you got, your original dictionary is used to call the same function, but with the value associated with the **age** attribute. Then your profile variable when called a second time is of type 'int', and as you know, a[b] does not work if a is a non-indexable like an integer.

Comment: *indexable* not *iterable*

Comment: Changed. Forgot that sets were a thing.

Answer (score 1):

You made a [recursive function](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/understanding-recursive-functions-python), and the only reason you don't get a `RecursionError`, is because a `TypeError` is thrown first.

Think about what is happening:

First you pass a dictionary to `getdoubleage`, then you find pass the value for the `"age"` key (which is 10), to `getdoubleage` again.  Now the code for `getdoubleage` starts over from the beginning of the function, and tries to run `return getdoubleage(10["age"]) * 2`, which will always throw a `TypeError` because you can't use `[]` on integers.

To fix this simply return the *value* that you get from the dictionary:

```
def getdoubleage(profile):

    return profile["age"] * 2
```